# Pusher Client, authEndpoint field in .NET Core SDK

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, websocket, pusher

I need to set the authEndpoint in the PushClient Object. The documentation describes this field as part of the Properties of the client Object but in the references of the PusherOptions I don't see it

```
public class PusherOptions
{
    public PusherOptions();

    public bool Encrypted { get; set; }
    public IAuthorizer Authorizer { get; set; }
    public string Cluster { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ClientTimeout { get; set; }
    public ITraceLogger TraceLogger { get; set; }
}
```

How I'm supposed to set the authEndpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The authpoint must be setted in an instance of IAuthorizer, HttpAuthorizer

```
Authorizer= new HttpAuthorizer("authUrl")
```